# Grails 3 -store session data in controller with scope='session'?

Tags: grails, grails-controller

Somehow it seems like it might be a bad idea, but wondering if it recommended or not when you are using session scope in a controller to store session data in controller fields, say for example, as a kind of caching for user data so you have don't have to keep hitting the db to get frequently requested information for a particular user?

And, by the way, just wondering how long the server holds on to the controller instance in that case.  If someone leaves the browser tab open for a week, not using it, does the controller instance for that session hang around indefinitely consuming resources on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You could, use a controller like that, but why not just simply use a cache instead? There are lots of really good caches out there (Spring cache for instance) which will likely be more extensible than this approach.

Session management (and when they expire) is handled by your application container (e.g. Tomcat, JBoss, Websphere, etc.). In most cases without interaction with the server (e.g. hitting a URL or page) they expire after a default of 20 minutes. So once a session expires, the session scoped controller instance becomes a candidate for being cleaned up and removed.